# Why AfterReturning PointCut is not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

My pointcut for method `public int quantity()` in `ShoppingCart.java` is not working.  I am trying to create a pointcut to capture the return value of the method `public int quantity()` but the relevant advice for `@AfterReturning` pointcut doesn't seem to get invoked even after the quantity method is invoked by main method (See the file `AuthenticationAspect.java` which is trying to define an afterReturning Pointcut).

File ShoppingCart.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ShoppingCart {

    public int quantity()
    {
        System.out.println("\n Quantity method called");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationAspect.java

```
package org.example;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthenticationAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.example.ShoppingCart.quantity())")
    public void afterReturningPointCut()
    {
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "afterReturningPointCut()", returning = "retVal")
    public void afterReturning(String retVal)
    {
        System.out.println("The quantity used is " + retVal);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfig.class);

        ShoppingCart cart = context.getBean(ShoppingCart.class);

        cart.quantity();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A `returning` clause restricts matching to only those method executions that return a value of the specified type.

The `ShoppingCart.quantity()` method returns `int`, therefore it doesn't match the `String` return type declared in the advice. You can change the `retVal` type to `int` or to `Object`, which matches any return value.

For reference: [After Returning Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-advice-after-returning)